I am a beginner. Wrote the below amp script code. I have tried many things but cant get rid of this error
Below is my piece of code-
An expected comma is not found in the varible declaration.

Script: Var @fname,@lname,@plantype,@gender  ListID: 59096 Index:
14758

%%[ 
Var @fname,@lname,@plantype,@gender 
Set @fname = FristName 
Set @lname = LastName 
Set @plantype = Plan Type 
Set @gender = Gender  
]%% 

<p>
Hello %%= v(@fname) =%%! Here are your account details 
First Name: %%= v(@fname) =%% 
Last Name: %%= v(@lname) =%% 
Plan Type: %%= v(@plantype) =%% 
</p>


The issue is with @plantype because its contains a space in the value that you are trying to set. Please find the updated code
%%[
Var @fname, @lname, @plantype, @gender
Set @fname = FirstName
Set @lname = LastName
Set @plantype = [Plan Type]
Set @gender = Gender
]%%

Hello %%=v(@fname)=%%! Here are your account details:
First Name: %%=v(@fname)=%%
Last Name: %%=v(@lname)=%%
Plan Type: %%=v(@plantype)=%%


Thanks for the reponse Ranjan. I have edited the attribute name from "Plan Name" to "Membership", still error is same.

Membership doesn’t appear to be declared or printed in the snippet you are sharing. Any chance that a previous version did have it? It might be that the TEXT version of your email still has a previous version of your code. Click on the TEXT tab to refresh.

Make sure that there are no spaces in variable names and the field names are correctly referenced.
%%[
Var @fname, @lname, @plantype, @gender
Set @fname = FirstName
Set @lname = LastName
Set @plantype = PlanType
Set @gender = Gender
]%%

<p>
Hello %%= v(@fname) =%%! Here are your account details:
<br />First Name: %%= v(@fname) =%%
<br />Last Name: %%= v(@lname) =%%
<br />Plan Type: %%= v(@plantype) =%%
<br />Gender: %%= v(@gender) =%%
</p>

Added a space after each comma in the variable declaration, Corrected the field names to remove spaces (e.g., PlanType instead of Plan Type) and Added <br /> tags for line breaks in the HTML content.

You still need to fix the spaces between %%= and v( - as this will throw an error.
